# How to stream the contents after Stream.Concat to avoid intermediate List

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have two Lists A and B. I would like to merge them and stream again to form an Array.

I'm currently doing:

```
List<String> aggregate  = Stream.concat(A.stream(), B.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
String[] final = aggregate.stream().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[10]);
```

Here, I'm having two intermediate lists that I'm just using to grab the final Array. Is there a way I can eliminate the two collect(Collectors.toList()) and write this in a single line?

Thank you

Comment: `Stream.concat(A.stream(), B.stream()).limit(10).toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: Thanks, I get the following compilation error:
The method toArray(IntFunction<A[]>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String[])

Edit: My Bad, I didn't see your change! Thanks it worked

Comment: Even with what you had, why would you `collect` and then again `stream`. What sense does *stream the contents after `Stream.concat`* even make? Besides `final` is a keyword!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to collect at all you can directly use `.toArray()`

```
String[] res = Stream.concat(A.stream(), B.stream()).limit(10).toArray(String[]::new);
```

And if you want concat the stream and then get as array separately without collecting

```
Stream<String> aggregate  = Stream.concat(A.stream(), B.stream());
String[] res = aggregate.limit(10).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
Stream.concat(A.stream(), B.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will return a list. If you want to be it an array, then do

```
 Stream.concat(A.stream(), B.stream()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

for multiple streams we can do like

```
Stream.concat(firstStream, concat(secondStream, concat(thirdStream, fourthStream))).toArray(String[]::new);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: How is this different from what the author already has?

Comment: There is no need to collect once its concatenated , just apply the operation and collect it.

Comment: The question is asking for an array.

Comment: @hev1 modified the answer. Thanks